# Can a kraken.js backend change the content of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, express, dust.js, kraken.js

Using kraken.js (an express.js framework) I'm building a localized website.
In the header, there are 3 links to change the language

```
FR | EN | DE
```

If the locale is set to FR (according to a cookie) I would like to have the FR link underlined (with a `class="active"` attribute in html). Sadly, I can't find where to add this behavior. Do I have to use a frontend script or can I add this behavior in dust.js (included in kraken.js) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it in dust -- but you're going to have to dig a bit or build middleware to copy the value to where dust can see it.

From the `krakenjs-examples/with.i18n` project, its `lib/locale.js` middleware:

`module.exports = function () {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        var locale = req.cookies && req.cookies.locale;
        //Set the locality for this response. The template will pick the appropriate bundle
        res.locals.context = {
            locality: locale
        };
        next();
    };
};`

That puts it on `res.locals` where dust can find it.